# Able to add an option on click but unable to remove it (Toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to on click toggle add the option to the select menu but then be able to remove it if I click again (Deselect). So far I am able to add an individual value on click to the selection menu but unable to remove it (toggle add toggle remove)

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="listview lv-user m-t-20">
    <div class="lv-item media">
            <div class="lv-title">this is test 1</div>  
            <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 1"> 
            </div>
    </div>
     <div class="lv-item media">
            <div class="lv-title">this is test 2</div>  
            <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 2"> 
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lv-item media">
            <div class="lv-title">this is test 3</div>  
            <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 3"> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".lv-item").on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).find('#screen_name_test').val());
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).find('#account_selected').toggle();
  $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
    value: $(this).find('#social_media_test').val(),
    text: $(this).find('#screen_name_test').val()
    }).attr('selected',true)
  );
});

if($(".lv-item").not('active'))
{
  $('#mySelect').remove($('<option>', {
  value: $(this).find('#social_media_test').val(),
  text: $(this).find('#screen_name_test').val()
  }).attr('selected',false)
  );
}
```

I have also created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35d8Lu9b/7/)

Comment: what is #social_media_test? it's not in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some different approach but it is pretty simple. Just have a look and let me know if it helps you anyway.

**<kbd>[Working:Example](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/35d8Lu9b/12/)</kbd>**

**HTML**

```
<div class="listview lv-user m-t-20">
    <div class="lv-item media">
        <div class="lv-title">this is test 1</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lv-item media">
    <div class="lv-title">this is test 2</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 2">
</div>
</div>
<div class="lv-item media">
    <div class="lv-title">this is test 3</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 3">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect[]" multiple></select>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**

```
$(".lv-item").on("click", function () {
    alert($(this).find('#screen_name_test').val());
    var curOption = $(this).find('#screen_name_test').val();

    var sts = $('#mySelect').find('option[value="' + curOption + '"]').length;
    if (sts == false) {
        $('#mySelect').append('<option value="' + curOption + '" selected>' + curOption + '</option>');
    } else {
        $('#mySelect').find('option[value="' + curOption + '"]').remove();
    }

});
```